# Как сделать поиск данных в бд с помощью ajax codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, ajax, поиск, codeigniter, ajax-load

Пытаюсь сделать **поиск данных** с помощью codeigniter 3, ajax.
Вот мой ajax:

```
  $('input:radio').on('change',function(){
   var value = $(this).data('val');
   alert(value);
    $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        url:"main/tur_search",
        data:{value:value},
    }).done(function(){
        $('.load').load('tur_search');
    });
```

А вот куда ajax отправляет данные:

```
  public function tur_search(){
    $keyword = $this->input->post('value');
    $this->load->model('Page_models');
    if ($keyword == ""){
        $data['tours'] = $this->Page_models->get_serach_result($keyword);
    }
    else{
        $data['tours'] = $this->Page_models->get_turs();
    }
    $this->load->view('tur.php',$data);
}
```

Модель:

```
public function get_serach_result($keyword){
    print_r($keyword);
$array = array('blok_title' => $keyword, 'tur_name' => $keyword);
$this->db->like($array);
$query  =   $this->db->get('main_turs');
return $query->result();
```

}

Получается есть див. в внутри дива через load грузятся данные (при загрузке страницы).
Почему то, в моем ajaxe не работает  $('.load').load('tur_search');
Подскажите, как можно лучше сделать?

Comment: Если `$keyword == ""` то вы по нему что-то ищете. Может наоборот - надо искать когда `$keyword` __не__ пустой?

Comment: `.load('tur_search')` грузит данные отдаваемые урлом `tur_search`. У вас есть такой урл? Он отдает что-то?

Comment: Может пора уже открыть консоль разработчика и там чего-нибудь поразглядывать?

Comment: @u_mulder да есть, отдает.

Answer (score 0):

Если я все правильно понял, то вам надо вот так:

```
$.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url:"main/tur_search",
    data:{value:value},
    success: function(data) {
        $('.load').text(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: text() же просто как строку выводит? а мне нужно чтоб все стили сохранились как блок с картинкой были, изначально они так и стоят

Comment: @Улан Хозяин-барин:  `$('.load').html(data);`